# JavaScript - IF statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have problem with IF statement. It doesn't execute even through condition in brackets is TRUE.

```
<script>
    alert(occ);
    if(occ == "true"){
        document.getElementById(occ).innerHTML = "Already registered";
        alert("done");
    }
</script>
```

Function `alert(occ);` does work: [Web screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0bk0.png)

Comment: Try if(occ === true){}. This may work

Comment: what you want to achive exactly

Comment: remove the quotes - `if(occ == true) {`

Comment: Removing quotes didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is not problem with your **if**

document.getElementById(occ).innerHTML='Already registered';

try instead this
document.getElementById(**'occ'**).innerHTML='Already registered';

Comment: I tried, but this don't work. I think there is problem with 'if' because alert("done"); don't execute too.

Comment: Sorry, there IS problem with `document.getElementById(occ).innerHTML='Already registered';`. `alert("done");` didn't execute because script stopped at `document.getElementById(occ).innerHTML='Already registered';` so it couldn't get there. But adding **'** still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

well, occ value must be boolean `true`

```
true == 'true'  // false
true ==  true   // true
```

suggest you use:

```
if(occ === true){
  .....
}
```

see it is work?

Comment: I tried this: `if(occ === true){ ...` and this: `if(occ === "true"){ ...` and this  `if(occ === 'true'){ ...` but unfortunately neither worked.